# setAppends on demand in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model that has a bunch of attributes attached to it. The problem that I am having is that I do not need all the attributes for index method in my controller I need just a few. I have tried to attach them with `setAppends` method but it does not seem to work.

Here is what I tried:

```
$orders = new Order;

$order->setAppends(['overdueBy'])-get();
```

This simply returns the orders but doesn't have attributed attached. If I call it as static method which I seen while looking for the answer on the internet it throws an exception, I need to paginate results as well as apply some filters like `orderBy` but if I do so then it calls the method on `Builder` class that doesn't have it. Calling it on each model retrieved will create n+1 problem.

Is it possible to have appends on demand?

Comment: What exactly is `overdueBy`? A relationship? A scope? Can you post the `Order` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setAppends` method is for a single row. So you can use it as follows:

`$order = Order::first(); // Or whatever you need`

`return $order->setAppends(['overdueBy]);`

It's also possible to iterate over your collection and set it per record

`$orders = Order::whichYouNeed();`

```
$orders->each(function($order) {
   $order->setAppends(['overdueBy']); 
});
```

And do whatever you want.

Comment: You can shorten it: `$orders->each->setAppends(['overdueBy']);`

Comment: how does it work when you do Order::all()? does it loop throw each one and then appends? How to eager load it than?

Comment: You can't use eagerLoading with appends, it will just append something to the json https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: @Matz So does it mean that $append = ['orderBy'] on Model::class does loop throw every model retrieved and then appends custom scopes?

Comment: I check now with laravel debug bar that's what it does unfortunately as it generates 20 extra queries when I append scope that does query to a relationship.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append data at runtime then you should use

`$order->setAppends(['overdueBy'])->toArray();`

But remember this will override existing properties of the collection

for reference see [Eloquent: Serialization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

I would suggest you should use `makeHidden` method for hiding unnecessary

attributes reference see [hiding attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)